# How to remove all characters in textfile after a specific character per line in python?

Tags: python, base64, text-files, decode

Suppose I have a textfile where each line is like this:

`QWERTYUIOP",12345678901234567890`

Some important text followed by the characters (",) then some other characters. How can I write a Python script to read each line of that textfile and remove all characters in each line that appear after (",)? I would also like to remove the ", characters themselves.

Then for each of the editted lines, I'd like to Base64 decode them and write them to a new textfile. I'm pretty sure I know how to do this part but I'm unsure about the editing part as described above.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Detecting (`index`) and removing (use slices) are covered well in other places.  The overall program logic is your responsibility.

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/), without specifics, and without your applicable research, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```py
file=open("file_name").readlines()
for i in file:
    required_string = i.split('",')[0]
    #your program to decode the required_string
```

I believe splitting lines by ", can help you overcome this problem. `required_string` is the string I believe you wanted. After this, you decode this string and save it in the text file as you wanted. Hope I solved the problematic part.